# Unable to sync AngularJS service with controllers (angular.copy)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have set up two controllers (Controller A and Controller B) and a service (Service). I am attempting to sync the data from controller A to the service, and present that information to Controller B.

Within my Service, I've established a variable `confirmdata` and get and set functions:

```
function setData(data) {
  confirmdata = angular.copy(data);
}

function getData() {
  return confirmdata;
}
```

In controller A I've created a function `sync`to sync information from the controller to the service:

```
this.sync = function () {
var data = {
payment: this.getpayment()
}
Service.setData(data);
```

In controller B I've assigned a function as:

```
this.sync  = function () {
this.viewData = Service.getData();
console.log('TestingData', this.viewData);
```

For a reason I am unaware of; my console log simply returns undefined when it should be returning the results of the `getpayment()` function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: controller B might be running before controllerA set the data to it?

Comment: @PSL might be right, put a console.log in your controllers to see which gets called first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are getting undefined would indicate that you haven't initialized 'confirmdata' in your service. Whether this is the actual issue though, isn't clear.  For a simple example, I would design your service like this:

```
myApp.factory('sharedService', [function () {
    var confirmdata = {};
    return {
        setData: function (newData) { confirmdata = newData; },
        getData: function getData() { return confirmdata;  }
    }
}]);
```

Take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xY84EHKi0Lr5QSpb6stj?p=preview). It gives an example of data being shared between controllers via a service.